# How to change color of QDockWidget float-button

Tags: c++, qt

I can't seem to change the close and float button color in a dock widget from back to white. This is when it is docked.

Here is what i have tried:

```
borderStyle.append(
"QDockWidget::close-button {color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background: rgb(100, 100, 100) }")
dock_->setStyleSheet(borderStyle);
```

The background color changes but the black 'X' and black float images don't.

Why? Anybody know how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Close and Dock signs are icon images you can change them.
refer  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qdockwidget

Open designer and dockwidget right click on dock widget and click on change stylesheet then paste following line, just remove url and click on add resources to change icon pic :

```
QDockWidget {
     border: 1px;
     titlebar-close-icon: url(:/new/Icon/Icon/Crop.jpg);
     titlebar-normal-icon: url(:/new/Icon/Icon/F_Circlensm_Icon.jpg);
 }

 QDockWidget::close-button{
border: solid black;
background-color:solid red;
icon-size: 20px; 
}
```

Try in this way HTH.

Comment: Umm, I've been to this page before posting here. That's where I got the example you see from me. Its not working for changing (foreground icon) color. But ,like i said, background color manipulation is no problem. Its the color (foreground) that won't change for me. Why? What am I doing wrong?